# Replace every occurrence string between two characters in a large text using regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have the following text

> This is fruit is ***$apple$*** and second fruit is  ***$mango$*** and the third fruit is ***$banana$***

Now in JavaScript we need to find text between ***$..$*** and replace with my own text on every occurrence randomly

This is fruit is ***$five apples$*** and second fruit is  ***$two mangoes$*** and the third fruit is ***$bananas are yellow$***

Something like this, the main objective is find all strings between ***$$*** and replace with new text.

How can I write simple JavaScript regular expression for this, or any other method which is fast?

Comment: `\$[^ ]*\$` is a start...have you tried building it yourself at all? Do you know regular expressions syntax?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
var text = "This is fruit is $apple$ and second fruit is $the mangoes$ and the third fruit is $ price \\$ of banana$";

var replace = ['hello', 'these', 'are', 'some', 'random', 'strings'];

var matches = text.match(/\$(?:[^\$\\]|\\.)*\$/g);

matches.forEach(function(match) {
  random = '$' + replace[Math.floor(Math.random() * replace.length)] + '$';
  text = text.replace(match, random)
});

alert(text);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is working fine for me, but help request on 2 additional items, 1) When we have spaces i.e $the mangoes$ in this case its not coming to matches.   2) how to use escape characters for ex: if i use \$ inside to ignore this dollar i.e. $ price \$ of banana$

Comment: I have updated the answer, but for escaping you have to use double \\
Here's a jsfiddle with it https://jsfiddle.net/uxv491rL/

Comment: Thanks for updating answer, this is what exactly i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

https://jsfiddle.net/mewcg3zo/

```
var text = "This is fruit is $apple$ and second fruit is $mango$ and the third fruit is $banana$";
var matches = text.match(/\$(.*?)\$/g);
var newText = ['$five apples$', '$two mangoes$', '$bananas are yellow$'];

$.each(matches, function(index, match) {
    text = text.replace(match, newText[index]);
});

alert(text);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is working fine for me, but help request on how to use escape characters for ex: if i use \$ inside to ignore this dollar i.e. $ price \$ of banana$